# Jackson - Java Objects with List<Map<String,String>> to Json String conversion

Tags: java, json, spring, solr, jackson

I would like to generate JSON String from Java object

```
public class Resource {

String name;
List<Item> items;

public String resourceAsJson(Resource resource) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resource);
}
```

Where Item

```
public class Item {
    Map<String, String> systemFields;
    Map<String, String> dataFields;
}
```

The form of the JSON String at this moment is

```
{
"name": "Person",
"items": [
    {
        "systemFields": {
            "systemField1": "xxx",
            "systemField2": "xxx",
            "systemField3": "x"
        },
        "dataFields": {
            "dataField1": "xxx",
            "dataField2": "xxx",
            "dataField3": "x"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

What I try to obtain is the different form of JSON (ommiting the Item and have "system fields" "data fields" in one Json table)

```
{
"Person":[
        {
        "systemField1": "xxx",
        "systemField2": "xxx",
        "systemField3": "Warsaw",
        "dataField1": "xxx",
        "dataField2": "xxx",
        "dataField3": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this with Jackson without changing the model?

Comment: `@JsonUnwrapped` might be what you are looking for

Comment: can you send the whole code block so that I can work around in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this where default representation of `POJO` is not what you want you need to implement custom serialisers. In your case they could look like below:

```
class ResourceJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Resource> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Resource value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName(value.getName());
        gen.writeObject(value.getItems());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

class ItemJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Item> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Item value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        writeMap(value.getSystemFields(), gen);
        writeMap(value.getDataFields(), gen);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    private void writeMap(Map<String, String> map, JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
        if (map != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                gen.writeStringField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can register them using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize` annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ResourceJsonSerializer.class)
class Resource {
```

and:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ItemJsonSerializer.class)
class Item {
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: Is there any option to use it only when I want to? I mean to serialize in this way just "on demand". I am asking because application save this model to JSON couple of time but only once I would like to have "simplified" one.

Comment: @PiotrSupel, take a look for example on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217671/convert-java-object-with-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-and-get-error-when-conver/55220222#55220222). In my answer you can find `SimpleModule` object. You can register custom serialisers with it and register it only for `ObjectMapper` when serialisers are needed. Also see: [Deserialization of java.utils.logging.Level class with Jackson returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578292/deserialization-of-java-utils-logging-level-class-with-jackson-returns-null/59585298#59585298)